# Can a vector field be conservative if its domain is not a star domain?

Tags: analysis, vector-fields

> Can a vector field be conservative if its domain is not a star domain?

I was trying to figure out whether the vector field
$$\vec{f}(\vec{x}):=\frac{1}{\lvert \lvert \vec{x} \rvert \rvert} \begin{pmatrix}x-2y\\x+2y\end{pmatrix}$$
is conservative on $\Bbb R^2 / \text{{$\vec{0}$}}$.

I used the criterion:

$$\vec{f}\space \text{is conservative} \iff \frac{dP}{dy}=\frac{dQ}{dx} \space \text{and the domain is a star domain}$$

In this case $\frac{dP}{dy}\not=\frac{dQ}{dx}$ so the test fails already but I was wondering if I could have also argued that the domain is not a star domain so the field is not conservative.

Can a vector field ever be conservative if its domain is not a star domain?

What is so special about star domains that makes them so essential when dealing with conservative vector fields?

Comment: A star domain is not usually part of the definition of a conservative vector field.  Perhaps the statement is "on a star domain, a vector field is conservative if and only if $\frac{dP}{dy}=\frac{dQ}{dx}$."  This statement only uses the star domain in the proof and does not mean star domains are required.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean. Suppose $$\frac{dP}{dy}=\frac{dQ}{dx}$$ 

holds but my domain $D$ is not a star domain. Can I conclude that my vector field is not conservative or can vector fields also be conservative on domains like the one I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Vector fields can be conservative on any domain, even if the special case of star shaped (or simply connected) doesn't occur.  In such a case, however, you can't use the test you mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The criterion would imply that the answer to your question is no, but the statement as written is incorrect. A correct modification of the statement is:

> If a vector field ${\bf F} = (P, Q)$ defined on the open subset $U \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ satisfies $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ and the domain $U$ of $\bf F$ is star-shaped, then $\bf F$ is conservative.

As the question observes, neither of the hypotheses here hold, so we can't conclude anything from this statement alone.

On the other hand, at least when $\bf F$ is $C^2$, the equality $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ is a necessary condition for conservativeness: If $\bf F$ is conservative, there is a function $f$ (called a *potential*) such that
$${\bf F} = \nabla f := \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right).$$
Then, by Clairaut's Theorem (the equality of mixed partials of sufficiently nice functions of two variables) we have
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{dx}\right) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{dy \, dx} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{dx \, dy} =\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}.$$ So, if $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$, then $\bf F$ cannot be conservative.

It is certainly possible for a vector field on a nonstarshaped domain to be conservative. To construct an example, simply pick any nonstarshaped (open) set $U \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ and any $C^1$ function $f : U \to \Bbb R^2$. Then, $\nabla f$ is conservative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So basically I cannot conclude that $F$ is defined on a star-shaped domain just by knowing $F$ is conservative? However, if I know $F$ to be a conservative vector field then I can conclude that it is the gradient of some scalar field $f$ ($F=\nabla f$). Would $f$ be the potential function?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is the potential function, and "it is the gradient of some scalar field" is sometimes taken as the definition of conservativeness of a vector field. And yes, starshapedness of the domain is not a requirement for conservativeness: To produce a counterexample, just pick any (open) nonstarshaped region $U$ and any $C^1$ function $f: U \to \Bbb R$; then, $\nabla f$ is conservative.

Comment: (That said, even though starshapedness is not necessary, we cannot drop that hypothesis in the statement in the answer, i.e., there is a vector field that satisfies $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ but which is not conservative; the statement implies that the domain of any such vector field is not starshaped.)

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it helpful.

Comment: Another way to get a conservative function on a non-star shaped domain is to take a conservative function on a star-shaped domain and restrict it to a non-star shaped subset of that domain.

Answer (score 5):

Usually the *definition* of a conservative vector field is this:
Let $\vec{f}$ be a vector field in an open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$.
It is called conservative if there is a scalar function $\Phi:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ so that $\vec f=\vec\nabla\Phi$.
This definition makes no assumptions about the geometry.

Then we have these two theorems:

1. If $f$ is conservative, then $\partial_1f_2=\partial_2f_1$.
2. If $\Omega$ is simply connected, then $\partial_1f_2=\partial_2f_1$ implies that $f$ is conservative.

Star-shaped domains are simply connected, but the assumption is more general than that.
Using the first theorem we can see that since $f$ fails the conclusion, it must also fail the assumption; that is, $f$ is not conservative.

The special thing about simply connected domains is that they have no holes: you cannot take a path around a point outside $\Omega$.
It is the existence of such paths that causes theorem 2 to fail if $\Omega$ is not simply connected.
(There is also a measure for how badly it fails for a given domain, namely the first de Rham cohomology group.)
Star-shaped domains are nice because you can find a very simple path between any two points (through the center).
In more general simply connected domains you need more complicated paths but the basic idea is the same.

(Similar ideas work in higher dimensions as well, but I restricted myself to the plane for simplicity.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So these statements are implications and not "iff statments" right? In other words $$f \space \text{is conservative} \implies \partial_1 f_2= \partial_2 f_1$$ 

and not

$$f \space \text{is conservative} \iff \partial_1 f_2= \partial_2 f_1$$

Comment: @SuH, yes, you always have the implication $\implies$. But you do have $\iff$ in some special domains, like star-shaped ones. The geometric assumption is only needed for one direction.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SuH, I'm glad if I could be of help. :)